# New network and tracert says first hop is the host I am tracing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, networking

Disclaimer: I am a n00b with setting up windows networks with AD. Another intermediate guy set this up.

So if I do tracert google.com, the first hop sows as the IP of google.com. I have never come across this before. I am not sure exactly what settings you wold need to see to figure this out, so if you let me know, I can surely supply them. I believe the 2nd hop is the modem. Also, the router is doing the DHCP for now, not the DC. If that matters.

```
C:\Users\Derek>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [74.125.224.233]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  lax04s08-in-f9.1e100.net [74.125.224.233]
2     8 ms     7 ms     7 ms  10.100.32.1
3    10 ms     8 ms     8 ms  70.169.77.214
4    17 ms    10 ms    11 ms  mcdlcorc01-te-0-4-0-2.ph.ph.cox.net [70.169.72.66]
5     8 ms     8 ms     9 ms  70.169.75.157
6    21 ms    23 ms    31 ms  68.1.5.139
7    23 ms    23 ms    20 ms  72.14.215.221
8    21 ms    21 ms    22 ms  209.85.248.187
9    21 ms    21 ms    29 ms  216.239.43.76
10    23 ms    21 ms    21 ms  lax04s08-in-f9.1e100.net [74.125.224.233]

Trace complete.
```

Edit: I also wanted to add that the reason I found this was because I noticed that sometimes sites would be slow to come up if at all, which I was thinking was a DNS issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Never seen that before, but Google seems to think it could be firmware issues with a router responding with incorrect info on the 1st hop.  What kind of router?

Comment: It is a NetGear ProSafe FVS318N Firmware Version: 4.3.0-19

Comment: I should add that clients that are not on the network yet don't have this issue. But they still go through the same router.